Dual boot issues after Ubuntu 24.04
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 with a tutorial, so later I can dual boot my Windows and Ubuntu. Everything worked great now that I have Ubuntu installed. The problem is after I restart my PC no boot menu is shown. OK that can happen, but when I enter the BIOS no other Boot option is displayed, only the Ubuntu 500GB SSD.


NOTE: I have Windows installed on another SSD (1TB) and I am certain that the files and everything still exist because, when I look at the SSD on Ubuntu I see all the Windows files

Now I looked for ways to fix it, but nothing worked. After one tutorial which told me to enable the launch CSM, I saw my 1TB drive in the boot menu, but not called as the Windows OS, it's just the name of the hard drive.


When I click on it to essentially start up this message shows up: "Reboot and select proper boot device...")

I am pretty certain that there must be a way to still access my Windows because the files are all present, but I can't manage to access it. Hopefully you can help me if anything isn't understandable please ask because this is really really important for me I would love to give you further information if needed. I really do need help and would be really thankful especially cause Windows is my main OS for stuff outside of coding like gaming, etc.
I followed countless tutorials on the Internet, but wasn't able to find one with the exact problem.
I have version 24.04.1 and I followed the following tutorial: youtube.com/watch?v=mXyN1aJYefc&t=324s My hardware is 16gb of Ram a Radeon rx 6650XT and an AMD 5 5600X
Partitioning details:
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 870 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: gpt  
Disk Flags:   

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  16.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      16.8MB  999GB   999GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 3      999GB   1000GB  726MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag, no_automount

Model: ATA CT500MX500SSD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  1128MB  1127MB  fat32              boot, esp
 2      1128MB  500GB   499GB   ext4 }


There is no such thing as the latest version. That could change in a day, Case in point 3 days ago was 24.04 now it is 24.04.1 You need to always give correct and accurate info in order to be able to offer any help. You never said what tutorial you followed but from the result it was not the right one your your hardware config.

Hey I am sorry that I didnt describe my Problem well I have the version 24.04.01 and I followed the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXyN1aJYefc&t=324s
My hardware is 16gb of Ram a Radeon rx 6650XT and an AMD 5 5600X

Do not add info for the question in comments. Please edit the question and add the info there.

Thank you for your answer, Did it!

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  You may have had Windows boot files in ESP on the now Ubuntu drive. That is a bit unusual as normally Windows has its own ESP - efi system partition on the same drive as install. But boot files often installed to whatever drive UEFI/BIOS sees as first.

Need to see your partitions detail. Boot into your Live Ubuntu USB. Then run command: sudo parted -l. Edit your question to include that output. Remember to put block code symbols { } around highlighted output, so it all lines up.

Hey oldfred thanks for your great answer - yes you are right I checked and the ssd with windows does not have a ESP but the SSD with linux does - here is the BootInfo: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/njyx8skfby/

Hey Paul Benson thank you very much for your comment, I edited my original message,  but it didnt seem to effect anything with puting the brackets around the output, nevertheless have you now got a clue what I can do thank you so much!

It looks like you haven't got the full details of the output of sudo parted -l. From what I'm seeing Windows is on your Samsung disk (sda), but on your Crucial disk (sdb) there's no partition other than the ESP (EFI System Partition). So where's your Ubuntu partition? Did you miss off some of the output? Please run that command again from the terminal, highlight all the output and copy it. Paste it into your question then highlight again and click the '{ }' symbol while output is highlighted.

Hi Paul Benson i entered the exact same command again and from what I can see nothing changed - ill add a image for better clarification https://imgur.com/cLOLbEF - have you got any idea what went wrong. Thank you so much

@Nikolas Bott. Command Is correct now. The last line was missing before. So you're saying when you boot up you are going straight to Ubuntu and not the grub menu? First of all CRM mode is incorrect. With CSM your computer can't read the Samsung disk. You need UEFI mode in this case. Your BIOS/UEFI  should be able to  select this option for starters. On your first image there must be a way of showing this.
